# How can I get row values by cell id in Excel

Tags: excel

I have table in Excel where stored some data about employees in one row (`usedID`, `salary`, `bonus`, etc). And  next page is receipt where I should retrieve data by `userID`. How can I do this?

Is there any specific function that let me grab appropriate data by unique usedID?
On the page receipt I will provide `usedID` or even cell id where it placed. For example, I know that `userID` placed in cell `B2`, and value that I need to get in cell `C2`. So this function should be like

```
(=[providedId].replace('B', 'C'))
```

And so on for other data. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please don't use code format in your question unless you are posting code. It is impossible to read this without a lot of scrolling.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)` function? I think it does exactly what you need.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data.  Sounds like you want to use a `vlookup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of use of VLOOKUP:

Imagine you have a table like this

```
USER ID   Salary
  ms122    12345
  ms153    54321
```

And these are in the range A1:B3

Then you can look up the salary of an employee with

`=VLOOKUP("MS123",A2:B3,2)`

Comment: @Alex_Bond - you're welcome. If this solves your problem, could you "accept" the answer (click the check mark to the left)?